# Failure Starting Android Virtual Device

Tags: android

I am trying to start a virtual device. When I press start in Android Virtual Device Manager, it shows a progress bar and in the middle (around 50%) it opens another window which I pasted here and closes. There's only one option for the video device which I believe the laptop's cam and when I press ok there's no virtual device running. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Prompt Window]

Comment: i too had similar issue.. on repeating "Run As android application" 1-2 times issue gets resolved

Comment: Did you try to just Press OK. I think the VD is trying to use the computer camera to represent the devices front facing camera.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you did not check any kind of a camera option. If you did you have to provide it with a source to get the image from.

The screen that the program is showing to you is the screen of the program that is asking for the image source.

Hope it helps.